# Why Doesn't This Javascript Work? Style Change

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I cant for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work:

javascript:

```
//==================================//
// resize_middle                            //
//----------------------------------//
// Resizes the content and left     //
// navigation div to make up the        //
// remains of available space.      //
//==================================//
function resize_middle()
{
    min_height = (window.innerHeight - 276) + "px";
    middle_left = document.getElementById("middle_left");
    middle_right = document.getElementById("middle_right");
    alert("its not going to work!");
    alert("here goes...");
    alert(min_height);
    middle_left.style.minHeight = min_height;
    alert("it works!");
    middle_right.style.minHeight = min_height;
}
//==================================//
// event handlers                           //
//==================================//
window.onload = resize_middle();
window.onresize = resize_middle();
```

html(body & javascript bit in head shown only):

```
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="central_column">
            <div id="top_left">
                <img src="./images/icon.png" alt="icon" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
            </div>
            <div id="top_right">
                top right
            </div>
            <div id="middle_left">
                middle left
            </div>
            <div id="middle_right">
                middle right
            </div>
            <div id="bottom">
                bottom
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'v used this before and have a working copy of some only slightly different code, but it works perfectly. I get the debugging alerts up until "it works!", which I don't get. Thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: `/* free-form comments\nvery useful they are */`

Comment: I **strongly** recommend using a proper debugger for JavaScript, like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this instead:

```
window.onload = resize_middle;
window.onresize = resize_middle;
```

Because as having it resize_middle() the function is processed immediately and the result is added to the event. You want the function itself to be added to the event so you leave off the () unless your function returns a function for the event to use.

Comment: Catches everyone out at least once

Answer (score 4):

You need this instead:

```
window.onload = resize_middle;
window.onresize = resize_middle;
```

Currently you're *calling* those functions and assigning their return value to the event. What you want is to assign the functions *themselves* to the events, and let the events call them.

---

**Side note:**

Unless the variables in `resize_middle` are defined elsewhere and you intend for them to be accessible to the outer scope, it is good practice to use the `var` keyword when defining new variables.

```
function resize_middle()
{
      // Changed to use "var"
    var min_height = (window.innerHeight - 276) + "px";
    var middle_left = document.getElementById("middle_left");
    var middle_right = document.getElementById("middle_right");

    alert("its not going to work!");
    alert("here goes...");
    alert(min_height);
    middle_left.style.minHeight = min_height;
    alert("it works!");
    middle_right.style.minHeight = min_height;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = resize_middle;
```

Read this resource on [assigning event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html#link2).

Comment: Oh you are joking me! I can't beleive this! Why does this work?

Comment: @Ell: because `resize_middle` evaluates to _the function_, and `resize_middle()` evaluates to _the value returned by the function_.